# How to handle exception in using(Py.GIL()) block pythonnet

Tags: c#, python, .net, multithreading, python.net

Is there a way to handle exceptions in using the (Py.GIL()) block?

For example:

```
   using System;
   using Python.Runtime;

   public class Test{
        public static void Main(){
           using(Py.GIL()){
               try{
                   dynamic module = Py.Import("module");
                   dynamic result = module.function("argument");

                   Console.WriteLine(result);
               }
               catch(Excepiton ex){
                   // Handled Exception
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

I asked this question because I call a C# function which uses the `using(Py.GIL())` block. It is executed with a new thread which the Main thread waits for to finish.

It works for the first round, but for the next, it stops on the `using block`, and the application freezes without showing any exception.

I even tried to stop the Main thread from waiting for the execution, but the worker thread still stops at the `using block` of `Py.GIL()` after the first round.

For the thread execution, I am using the Thread pool.

```
Thread.Factory.StartNew(FunctionName);
```

Comment: Full reproducible example would be handy. Only one CLR thread can acquire the GIL at anytime time during execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue was caused by the way Python handles threads. The main thread must start the Python engine and enable threading.

```
PythonEngine.Initialize();
PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
```

Run the above code on the Main thread before using worker thread that uses `using(Py.GIL()) block`.